# What is the E/Z configuration of cyclic compounds?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, cis-trans-isomerism

What are the configurations of 1-bromo-3-methylcyclopent-1-ene and 1-nitro-2-(propan-2-yl)benzene? Are they *E* or *Z*? Are they *cis* or *trans*?

[image: 1-bromo-3-methylcyclopent-1-ene]
[image: 1-nitro-2-(propan-2-yl)benzene]

What are the rules for these types of isomerism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessary to include the *E/Z* descriptors for these compounds, because the alternative geometries would be far too strained to be stable molecules. However, there is no reason that we can't apply the rules to these compounds and assign the *E/Z* descriptor.

In each case, compare at the substituents on each side of the pi-bond. For the top compound, one side of the alkene has Br compared to a carbon group, and Br is higher priority. On the other side, hydrogen is lower priority than a carbon group. The higher priority groups are trans, which makes the geometrical stereochemistry *E*.

For the bottom compound, we must compare two carbon groups, and the alkene containing one is higher priority. On the other side, nitro is higher priority than the carbon group. Again, the higher priority groups are trans, which means that the stereochemistry is *E*.

[image: compounds of interest]

In general, it is unnecessary to define the *E/Z* stereochemistry until the ring size is 8.

Comment: What if it's a bicyclo compound.. Will it show cis - trans

Comment: @harambe it depends on the strain for the specific isomers you're thinking about. Feel free to open another question if you have an example in mind.

Answer (score 4):

#### What is the meaning of *cis* and *trans*?

*cis* means *on the same side* (or face), *trans* means *on the opposite side* (or face).

#### Can I use *cis* and *trans* for cylic compounds?

Yes, you can describe the relative orientation of substituents on a ring using *cis* and *trans*, such as in the case of 1,3-dibromcyclohexane.
[image]

#### Can I use *cis* and *trans* for alkenes?

Yes, in priciple. But you should rather use ***E*** and ***Z***. Note that these descriptors are taken from German.

[image]

*E* means **entgegen** and refers to **opposite** directions (or sites), while *Z* means **zusammen**, which is **together**, that is **the same** direction (or site).

#### What about the compounds in my question?

***E***/***Z*** or *cis*/*trans* are not applicable here.

In the first case, the $\ce{Br}$ atom is in the ring plane, the methyl group can be above or below it. You could describe the absolute stereochemistry at the centre bearing the $\ce{CH3}$ substituent using ***R*** or ***S***.

In the second case, there's no alkene at all but a disubstituted benzene. The relative orientation of the substituents on these systems can be described by assigning the proper numbers or by using the *ortho*- *meta*- or *para*-prefix. For this compounds, 2-isopropylnitrobenzene or *o*-isopropylnitrobenzene would be ok.